# How to use Knockout with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

I am using [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) in my mvc application. In knockout i am not actually creating any view models rather i am getting the view models from the server side as json object and using ko.mapping plugin i am crating a ko models in javascript.

Consider the scenario where i have a *StudentModel* which further have 2 nested models say *Academic* and *Address*.

Now with my limited knowledge of AMD and requirejs i have decided to create 3 modules *Student* , *Academic* and *Address* module and i have define it using requirejs *define* function in 3 separate js files, something like

**Academic.js moduels**

```
define(['knockout', 'dataservice'], function (ko, dataService) {

    return function (data) {
        var self = this;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

        ... //some extensions to model            

        self.save = function (self) {
            var academic = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);

            dataService.saveData(url, academic, function (response) {
                alert('saved');
            });
        };

        return self;
    };

});
```

**Address.js moduels**

```
define(['knockout', 'dataservice'], function (ko, dataService) {

    return function (data) {
        var self = this;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

        ... //some extensions to model            

        self.save = function (self) {
            var address = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);

            dataService.saveData(url, address, function (response) {
                alert('saved');
            });
        };

        return self;
    };

});
```

**Student.js moduels**

```
define(['knockout', 'dataservice', 'academic', 'address'], function (ko, dataService) {


});
```

This is what i have done so far but i am not confident whether this is the right way to work with requirejs anf knockout. If it is not the right way (which i feel not) than can anyone please explain me the write way to use knockout with requirejs with the help of above mentioned example ??

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What you have posted above appear to be modules, so what is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: I want to know how i can initialize these modules from server data ?

Comment: Have you tried making an AJAX call back to the server from your view model?

Comment: Either do AJAX calls to get the data from the server as mentioned above or do something like `require(["Student"], function (Student) { ko.applyBindings(new Student(@MyDataInJsonFormatWhichIPassToMyStudentConstructor)); });` in your server side page (assuming that your server side technology is ASP.NET and you're using Razor syntax). Which approach is better varies and they both have advantages and disadvantages. I do favor the AJAX call method in general, but there are cases where the other approach is better and in some cases it might be best to use both methods.